# printing alternative output from 2 threads using semaphores

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning about the use of semaphores and multi threading in general but am kind of stuck. I have two threads printing G and H respectively and my objective is to alternate the outputs of each thread so that the output string is like this;

```
G
H
G
H
G
H
```

Each of the two classes has a layout similar to the one below

```
public class ClassA extends Thread implements Runnable{

     Semaphore semaphore = null;
     public ClassA(Semaphore semaphore){

         this.semaphore = semaphore;
     }

     public void run() {

        while(true)
        {
            try{
                semaphore.acquire();
                for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
                    System.out.println("F");

                }
                Thread.currentThread();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
            semaphore.release();
        }

    }

}
```

below is my main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

    ClassA clasA = new ClassA(semaphore);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(clasA);
    ClassB clasB = new ClassB(semaphore);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(clasB);
    t1.start();
    t2.join();
    t2.start();
```

The output I am getting is way too different from my expected result. can anyone help me please? did I misuse the semaphore? any help?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use intrinsic locks or reentrant locks or semaphores or whatever, just using locks doesn't enforce any order

Comment: ok, would you please suggest a path forward to obtain the expected order? what would you say is the weakness of the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Semaphores can't help you solve such a task.

As far as I know, JVM doesn't promise any order in thread execution. It means that if you run several threads, one thread can execute several times in a row and have more processor time than any other. So, if you want your threads to execute in a particular order you can, for the simplest example, make a static boolean variable which will play a role of a switcher for your threads. Using wait() and notify() methods will be a better way, and [Interface Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) will be the best way I suppose.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Solution {
    public static boolean order;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new ThreadPrint("G", true);
        Thread t2 = new ThreadPrint("O", false);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println("Finish");
    }

}

class ThreadPrint extends Thread {

    private String line;
    private boolean order;

    public ThreadPrint(String line, boolean order) {
        this.line = line;
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int z = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    if (order == Solution.order) {
                        System.out.print(line + " ");
                        Solution.order = !order;
                    }
                }
                sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BTW there can be another problem cause System.out is usually an Operation System buffer and your OS can output your messages in an order on its own.

P.S. You shouldn't inherit Thread and implement Runnable at the same time

```
public class ClassA extends Thread implements Runnable{
```

because Thread class already implements Runnable. You can choose only one way which will be better for your purposes.

You should start a thread then join to it not vice versa.

```
t1.start();
t2.join();
t2.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, locks themselves do not enforce any order and on top of that, you cannot be certain when a thread starts (calling `Thread.start()` will start the thread at some point in the future, but this might take a while).

You can, however, use locks (like a `Semaphore`) to enforce an order. In this case, you can use two Semaphores to switch threads on and off (alternate). The two threads (or `Runnables`) do need to be aware of each other in advance - a more dynamic approach where threads can "join in" on the party would be more complex.

Below a runnable example class with repeatable results (always a good thing to have when testing multi-threading). I will leave it up to you to figure out why and how it works.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class AlternateSem implements Runnable {

    static final CountDownLatch DONE_LATCH = new CountDownLatch(2);
    static final int TIMEOUT_MS = 1000;
    static final int MAX_LOOPS = 10; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        try {
            AlternateSem as1 = new AlternateSem(false);
            AlternateSem as2 = new AlternateSem(true);
            as1.setAlternate(as2);
            as2.setAlternate(as1);
            executor.execute(as1);
            executor.execute(as2);
            if (DONE_LATCH.await(TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Done");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Timeout");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

    final Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);
    final boolean odd;
    AlternateSem other;

    public AlternateSem(boolean odd) { 
        this.odd = odd;
    }

    void setAlternate(AlternateSem other) { this.other = other; }
    void release() { sem.release(); }
    void acquire() throws Exception { sem.acquire(); }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (odd) {
            other.release();
        }
        int i = 0;
        try {
            while (i < MAX_LOOPS) { 
                i++;
                other.acquire();
                System.out.print(odd ? "G " : "H ");
                release();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DONE_LATCH.countDown();
    }
}
```